# Verify folder name in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

How can I veify a folder name in a bash script.

I am in the folder named "test". Now I want to check the is really "text".

I have tried the following:

```
cd tmp
mkdir testfolder
cd testfolder
if [["${PWD##*/}"]] == "testfolder"
then echo "ok"
fi
done
```

But always get the error, that testfolder not found, it tries to run if as a command.

Thanks

Comment: Please always include the exact error messages you get in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual check condition should have been

```
if [ "${PWD##*/}" == "testfolder" ];
```

Or you can use the `test` operator `[[]]` with the return code of the comparison performed, something like:-

```
 [[ "${PWD##*/}" == "testfolder" ]] && echo "Match"
```

Comment: you have to wait some minutes, so not always :-)

Comment: nit: If you use `[`, you should use `=`.  That is `if [ "${PWD##*/}" = testfolder ];`  Most modern shell's builtin implementation of `test` will recognize `==`, but `/bin/[` on a recent Darwin (15.6.0) throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the whole comparison into `[[ ... ]]`:

```
if [[ ${PWD##*/} == testfolder ]]
```

Also note that spaces around `[[` aren't optional. Double quotes aren't needed in `[[ ... ]]`, but they are needed if you switch to single `[ ... ]`.

Comment: thank you I think I have tried this 10 times before but now it is working :-)